# To fetch the datatype of a column, present in the custom type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table which has two `varchar` columns where the raw data is stored. This raw data contains value and the field name. Field name is like `my_cursor.attribute1`. This cursor is of the data type (`my_custompackage.custom_data_type`).
Now, I need to get the data type of the column present in the `custom_data_type`.

This is wrong, but to give an idea it's something like

```
my_custompackage.custom_data_type.attribute13
```

But so far, I couldn't achieve anything. I have tried taking the value into a separate variable. Like `

```
select field_name into temp_variable from dual;
```

Then

```
select dump(temp_variable) into my_data_type
```

but it didn't work and I was getting the string value. So, could you please tell me how to proceed with this?

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not _fields_.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create` statements for the tables and types in question and your PL/SQL code that shows the (complete) declaration of the cursor and your code that uses the result of that query. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: The user_tab_columns view contains information about the columns of a table in your schema.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to build some form of dynamic processing, maybe for an [Entity-Attribute-Value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)? There is no standard process for this sort of thing, it's always bespoke. So you need to post a complete test case for this: sample data, expected output, the business logic you're trying to implement. You won't get a timely and helpful answer without it.